# JavaScript trim character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete "()" from each value. How would I do that?

```
var arr = ["(one)","(two)","(three)","(four)","(five)"];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is every value going to start and end with `(` and `)`?

Comment: Yes, really I want to delete ( and ) from each values.

Answer (score 4):

Since all the other answers are unnecessarily complicated, here's a simple one:

```
arr = arr.map(s => s.slice(1, -1));
```

You can do it in-place too if you prefer; the important part is `.slice(1, -1)`, which takes a substring starting from the character at index `1` (the second character) and ending before the last character (`-1`).

[`String.prototype.slice` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: would fail for `"test"`

Comment: @Tibrogargan: See the clarifying comment where the asker confirmed that *every* value would start and end with `(` and `)`.

Comment: `s.substr(1, s.length -2)` is more efficient than `slice(1, -1)` and a for loop is more efficient than `map`.  How come you chose them?  Never mind, substr and slice seem to be about the same w/ more testing

Comment: @Tibrogargan C would be even more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

use [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0kbytzc(v=vs.94).aspx)

```
var arr = ["(one)","(two)","(three)","(four)","(five)"];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
var x = arr[i];
x = x.replace(/[()]/g,"");
console.log(x);
}
```

note:
i dedited, because [alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155639/alexander-omara) was right

so u need to use regex, "g" for search globally,
"[" "]" to find all character inside

Comment: Would fail for `"(test(ing)123)"`, if the OP cares.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ["(one)","(two)","(three)","(four)","(five)"];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var arrLength = arr[i].length -2;
    var shortArr = arr[i].substr(1,arrLength);
    console.log(shortArr);
}
```

This gets one character less on the front and back

Answer (score 0):

This matches `(` followed by anything that isn't `)` followed by `)`.  Would also fail for `"(test(ing)123)",` (if you care)

```
var arr = ["(one)","(two)","(three)","(four)","(five)"];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/g, "$1");
}
```

This is much more simple/faster (but arguably more brittle):

```
var arr = ["(one)","(two)","(three)","(four)","(five)"];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].substr(1, arr[i].length - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fast and should work no matter how many parenthesis are in the string, it will remove them all.

```
arr[i] = arr[i].split(/\(|\)/g).join("");
```

Comment: This isn't fast.  It's even slower than my regex

Comment: @Tibrogargan lol, you may have a point with my regex being slow, I am not very proficient with regex. I could have did this  '/[\\(\\)]/g' for my regex, but i have no idea if it is more efficient... when I said "fast" I was refering to using the string.split() and string.join combination in javascript... I probably should have clarified.

Comment: @Tibrogargan this answer does pass all test cases mentioned on this page though, including "(test(ing)123)", where your "faster" regex would actually fail... so one could argue whether your regex is "faster" : )

Comment: fails for `"(test", (or any string where there are non balanced parentheses) but since the OP said that the only case is having open/closing parentheses at the start and end a number of us are over-generalizing.

Comment: @Tibrogargan actually the only thing that FAILS here is your logic, and if you ran your string "(test" against my code above, the code would remove the '(' from the string... The code I wrote does not care if there are balanced sets of parenthesis, it literally will just find all '(' characters and ')' characters and split on those characters. Then it will join all remaining strings together. essentially removing '(' or ')'... Stop reading and criticizing code, and actually go WRITE some code. You will learn more that way, and you may even come to understand my code above one day as well.

Comment: you're getting really defensive for no reason.  The OP said 'I want to delete "()"' ... not "(", but since the question itself is ambiguous it's all a matter of interpretation.  Given that he clarified to say he the parentheses are just at the start and the end, both of us are wrong, it would be incorrect to remove them from the middle.